# MongoDB, How to set transaction to CRUD?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There is a method which contain `findOne` and `updateOne` in my project.

When my server got a delay and delayed requests were processed at once.

And `findOne` brought data before `updateOne` ran in precious method.

The value of a particular column should not be below zero, but this phenomenon has led to (-).

Can I set transaction to CRUD in MongoDB without replica?

If i can't, how can i handle this situation?

Here is Example of my code.

1) document

```
{ _id: ObjectID, name: 'name', stack: 100 }
```

2) method (to check and reduce stack)

```
let method = async (req, res) => {
    let pool = await db.connect()
    let findTarget = await pool.collection('storage').findOne({ _id: req.targetID })
    if((findTarget.stack - req.stackCountToReduce) > 0 ) {
        let update = await pool.collection('storage').updateOne(
            { _id: req.id },
            { $set: { stack: { $inc: req.stackCountToReduce }}}
        )
    }
}
```

3) After Delay (each request reduce 30 stacks)

```
{ _id: OjbectID, name: 'name', stack: -140 }
```